# Animated products slider like toyota.com

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, jquery-animate

Toyota.com have products slider, every tab display div, and inside that div there is ul, the items of the ul (the vehicles) appear from out side the screen to be side by side,
then you can scroll to show the next group of vehicles!

The question is, how did they animate the cars to appear this way when i open any of the tabs?!

the tabs system is easy, showing the next vehicles is kinda easy, all the problem in the animated start of the vehicles!

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin might can help you : http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/